# Loop through list items and check for width in-line

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to loop through a list using jquery and find if any of the spans have a set width of 95%.  If it does, then change the color to BG color to red or if it's 50% change the BG color to yellow.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

I have started the loop.

**JQUERY**

```
// .skills = UL

$('.skills').each(function(i) {
var list = $(this).find('li span');

    if (list.attr('style').indexOf('width') == 95) {
        alert('hello');
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="column strengths">

    <ul class="skills">
        <li class="html"><b class="centered">HTML</b><div class="meter"><span style="width: 95%"></span></div></li>
        <li class="css"><b class="centered">CSS</b><div class="meter"><span style="width: 50%"></span></div></li>
        <li class="js">JS</li>
        <li class="jquery">Jquery</li>
        <li class="java">Java</li>
        <li class="php">PHP</li>
        <li class="ps">PS</li>
        <li class="ai">AI</li>
     </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Probably would be a good idea to post the HTML.

Comment: in if you should use === or == instead of =

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. The if statement is already set to '==' but still does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `indexOf` returns the position of a substring within a string, or -1 if not found.  So it will never equal 95, unless the letters **width** begin at position 96 of the style.
   You could do this instead:  `$(this).attr('style').indexOf('width: 95%') > -1`
2. You cannot assign a width to an inline element with static positioning (`span`).
3. Try to avoid using inline CSS.  Move your styles to an external CSS file instead.
4. Instead of searching the style attribute, consider checking the `width` style itself:

```js
$('.skills li span').each(function() {
  if(this.style.width === '95%') {
    alert('hello');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="skills">
  <li class="html"><b class="centered">HTML</b><div class="meter"><span style="width: 95%"></span></div></li>
  <li class="css"><b class="centered">CSS</b><div class="meter"><span style="width: 50%"></span></div></li>
  <li class="js">JS</li>
  <li class="jquery">Jquery</li>
  <li class="java">Java</li>
  <li class="php">PHP</li>
  <li class="ps">PS</li>
  <li class="ai">AI</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can more easily cycle through the UL for spans like this:

```
$('.skills li span').each(function(i) {

});
```

Throw an if statement in there checking for width. "this" will be the span itself.